# How to calculate the size of a file list (not a directory)?

Tags: files, disk-usage

This command:

```
$ time (\ls /path/to/lots/of/dir*/*/*/*.ext > inputs.txt )

real    1m9.064s
user    1m3.265s
sys     0m5.993s
```

Gives me a huge list of file names inside the file "inputs.txt".

I need to know the total size of all files described in inputs.txt, preferably without list all of them.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the option `-c` of `du`:

```
du -csh /path/to/lots/of/dir*/*/*/*.ext
```

To show only the final count, you can use `tail -n 1`:

```
du -csh /path/to/lots/of/dir*/*/*/*.ext | tail -n 1
```